# window.localStorage() to set language preferences

Tags: javascript, angular, local-storage, angular-local-storage

I'm trying to make is so that when a user selects their language preference on my site, it will be stored, so that if they were to refresh the page or come back, their selected language would still be there.

I'm doing this in Angular, and here is my code:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title: string = 'app';
  currentLanguage: string;
  currentPage: string;
  @ViewChild('bottom') bottomSection: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild('top') topSection: ElementRef;

  constructor(private global: GlobalProvider, private translate: TranslateService, private scrollService: ScrollToService, private elementRef: ElementRef, private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router) {
    translate.setDefaultLang('en');
    this.changeLanguage('en');
    this.currentLanguage = localStorage.getItem(this.currentLanguage);
  } 

  changeLanguage(language: string) {
    this.translate.use(language);
    this.currentLanguage = language;
    localStorage.setItem(this.currentLanguage, language);
  }
```

The language on the page change fine, but I cant seem to get the localStorage working. I am a beginner, so the answer might be obvious, but can anyone explain to me what I'm doing wrong and how to get the language preferences to be stored?

Comment: Are you seeing any error in console?

Comment: No, I'm not seeing any errors

Comment: localStorage.setItem('language', language); is most likely more what you're looking for - what you're doing now is basically calling changeLanguage('en'), then calling localStorage.setItem('en', 'en') which makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

To use **[localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)** you should use `key` `value` pair.

The issue with your code in this line.

```
localStorage.setItem(this.currentLanguage, language);
```

Because of this every time a new variable called `this.currentLanguage` will be stored in localstorage.

Try this to store item:

```
localStorage.setItem('selectedLanguage', language);
```

to get item:

```
localStorage.getItem('selectedLanguage');
```

Comment: I've tired this but it hasn't fixed the issue. Am i calling the function in the right place do you think?